# Using Wildcard find and replace in a CSV CNC file using Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, csv, wildcards

Hi I have a requirement to remove every occurrence of the "LIP_CUT,number.number," out of pages of code.

I am newbie to this type of argument structure and cannot get any results so far.

Any help appreciated please.

Regards

Ian

Typical line layout below

3BOLTA,4374.00,DIMPLE,4525.15,LIP_CUT,4525.15,3BOLTA,4525.15,DIMPLE,4974.00,LIP_CUT,4974.00,3BOLTA,5449.50

Needs to read

3BOLTA,4374.00,DIMPLE,4525.15,3BOLTA,4525.15,DIMPLE,4974.00,3BOLTA,5449.50

Comment: Dave, You're a star!

Comment: I've been trying blindly with \'s .'s and brackets for some time this morning and got nowhere.

Comment: This worked straightaway with the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a find and replace, but select 'Regular Expression', and put in the following in the 'Find what' box:

```
LIP_CUT,[0-9]+\.[0-9]+,
```

Make sure nothing is in the 'Replace' box.

So, just by way of a small explanation:

- '+' means 1 or more occurances
- '\.' means I'm actually looking for a '.' - just '.' on its own means any character
- square brackets allow me to specify a range of possible characters - in this case anything from 0-9

More info can be found [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) if you find this stuff fascinating.